# How to convert latitude and longitude from decimal degrees to degrees, minutes, and seconds in Python

Tags: python

I was wondering if anyone knows what is wrong with this code converting decimal degrees in to degrees, minutes, and seconds:

```
while True:

latitude = float(input("Enter a Decimal Degree latitude: "))
print(latitude)
longitude = float(input("Enter a Decimal Degree longitude: "))
print(longitude)

print("Result: ")

deg = int(latitude)
min = int((latitude - deg) * 60)
sec = ((latitude - deg) * 60) - min
DMS = str(deg) + u"\u00b0" + str(min) + "'" + str(sec) + "'' "
for latitude in range(-90, 90):
    if latitude < 0:
        direction = "S"
    elif latitude > 0:
        direction = "N"
print(DMS + direction)

deg = int(longitude)
min = int((longitude - deg) * 60)
sec = ((longitude - deg) * 60) - min
DMS = str(deg) + u"\u00b0" + str(min) + "'" + str(sec) + "'' "
for longitude in range(-180, 180):
    if longitude < 0:
        direction = "W"
    elif longitude > 0:
        direction = "E"
print(DMS + direction)

while True:
    another = input("Shall this program run another conversion? (Y/N)")
    if another in ("Y", "N"):
        break
    print("This question needs a proper answer.")
if another == "Y":
    continue
elif another == "N":
    break
```

It keeps going outside of the limits of the values for latitude and longitude. What could be wrong?

Comment: For which values of `latitude` and `longitude` does it exceed the limits?

Comment: Please fix your indenting. Also, post a minimal example, if possible.

Comment: The `for latitude in range(-90, 90):` and `for longitude in range(-180, 180):` loops are useless. `direction` will always be equal to `N` and `E` after them. Surely, this is not intended. You probably don't need the loops at all. Also, `latitude` = 89 and `longitude` = 179 after them. This is probably the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you may have a problem when you enter in values higher than the normal ranges for latitude or longitude. For instance if a user enters in 200 degrees for longitude they would get 200 deg 0 min 0 sec but you would want it to return -20 degrees 0 min 0 sec because it wrapped around the dateline. You need to implement that behavior in your code like this:

```
limited_longitude = (longitude + 180.0) % 360.0 - 180.0
deg = int(limited_longitude)
min = int((limited_longitude - deg)*60)
...
```

In the above code the `%` is the modulus operator which takes the remainder after division e.g. the `380 % 360 = 20`. Since longitude is -180 to 180 you have to shift the whole thing by 180 degrees before and after to get the right affect.

You would need to figure out similar logic for latitude.

Comment: Now, I need to fix a few more things. The one that is most important is making there are no negatives when the degrees are N and E.

Comment: Oh, and S and W as well.